# Get running instance of application from WMI process?

Tags: vbscript, wmi, office-automation

I'm trying to get hold of **running instances** of MS Access 2010+ (on Win10) but the usual tip; `GetObject(, "Access.Application")` ... for works only for **hidden instances** started by myself with script, but **not** any instances started from GUI by the user.

And yes, I've read perhaps ten or more google hits on the subject, both on WMI and GetObject, but I seem to have missed something important.

However, I've tried the code below and I can get hold of any **process** of running Access instances in this way, and I can even .terminate() them, but, that's **not** what I want to do. Instead I want to grab the process and assign it to a usable (correct type) Access variable (see "OutInstance" in the code below) :

[***Edit***: Using WHERE clause, and skipped Exit as to retrieve the last instance]

```
Public Function GetRunningInstance(sAppName sComputer, ByRef OutInstance)
    Dim oWMIService
    Dim wProcesses
    Dim oPrc

    GetRunningInstance = False
    Set OutInstance = Nothing

    if sComputer = "" then sComputer = "."
    Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=" & _
        "impersonate}!\\" & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set wProcesses = oWMIService.ExecQuery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process " & _
        "WHERE Name = '" & sAppName & "'")

    For Each oPrc in wProcesses
            ''' oPrc.Terminate()      ''' Works, I can shut down Access...
            Set OutInstance = oPrc
            GetRunningInstance = True 
            ''' By not exiting we get the last instance.
    Next

End Function
```

Now, after trying to get hold of an instance, **how do I "cast" the process to a usable Access application variable in this VBScript?**

```
Sub Test_DoStuff()
    Dim InstProc
    Dim AccessApp

    If GetRunningInstance("msaccess.exe", "127.0.0.1", InstProc) Then
        Set AccessApp = ''' cast 'InstProc' to my "Access.Application" somehow?
    Else 
        Set AccessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    End If

    ''' 
    ''' Doing my stuff
    ''' 

    AccessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
    AccessApp.DoCmd.Quit
End Sub

Test
```

I (also) don't understand why `GetObject(, "Access.Application")` doesn't work in all cases. Permissions? (I understand that it's 'unsafe' to close a database currently being used by a user, but also that can be dealt with).

// Rolf